# How to describe the maths behind this function

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters, helper

This is a Decimal to Binary converter. I need help explaining the math behind is as I don't have a clue how to explain all the Shifts etc.

```
number = int(raw_input("Enter the Number:"))
binary = ''
while number > 0:
    binary = str(number % 2) + binary 
    number >>=1
print(binary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop builds up a string which represents a binary value.

**str(number % 2)** finds the lowest bit of the number (either 0 or 1).

**binary = str(number % 2) + binary** adds the bit to the left end  of string **binary**

**number >>=1** removes the low bit now that we're done with it

**while number > 0** continues until the number is 0

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are converting 56 to binary.

When right shift by 1 bit, 56 (111000) becomes 28(011100)

**Note:** The right shift operator causes the bit pattern in the first operand to be shifted right the number of bits specified by the second operand. Bits vacated by the shift operation are zero-filled for unsigned quantities

Like this, the variable, **number** is right shifted by 1 till it is greater than 1 and every time, the remainder of number divided by 2 (this will be 0 or 1 always) is appended to the result variable, **binary**

Finally, the variable **binary** will have the binary equvalent